# WPF explicit DataTemplate equivalent for implicit DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

By using implicit data template I can reference a template in a window resource without using a key in the template like so:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:FriendDetailViewModel}">
        <view:FriendDetailView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width= "200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="{StaticResource FriendDetailViewModel}">
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

i.e. the `FriendDetailViewModel` in the `ContentControl` can detect the `FriendDetailViewModel` in `DataTemplate` and display its contents properly.

But I'm trying to do it without an implicit data template, but I couldn't get the same result. For example, like this:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FriendDetailViewData">
        <view:FriendDetailView DataContext="{Binding FriendDetailViewModel}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width= "200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding FriendDetailViewData}">
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

The `ContentControl` simply prints `System.Windows.DataTemplate`. Is there a way to get the equivalent behaviour without using implicit data template?

Comment: is there a reason to break code which works?

Comment: It's for learning purposes, to know multiple ways to do something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment

```
Content="{StaticResource FriendDetailViewData}"
```

makes no sense. It assigns the DataTemplate to the Content property.

You would still want to use a FriendDetailViewModel instance as Content and set the ContentTemplate explictly:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FriendDetailViewData">
        <view:FriendDetailView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource FriendDetailViewModel}"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource FriendDetailViewData}"/>
```

Comment: So just to clarify, every ContentControl should have a template specified (like here)? And other classes that inherit from ContentControl (like buttons) have their own default templates already so defining them is not needed?

Comment: A ContentTemplate is needed when the Content is not a UI element. You somehow need to define how data is visualized. If no ContentTemplate is set for non-UI Content, the framework usually calls the ToString method of the Content object and passes the result to a TextBlock. For your edit suggestion, the assignment `Content="{StaticResource FriendDetailViewModel}"` is from your question. If there is a Binding instead, edit your question accordingly.